# How to pass an object using the Ajax.BeginForm() helper

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am trying to use the Ajax.BeginForm to post a message back to the server and I need to give a name to the form, i.e. use the parameter htmlAttributes. For that I am using the following signature:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendEmail", "Contacts", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "sendMessageArea" }, new { Name = "sendEmail" }))
```

This code doestn't work, it updates the whole page and the controller is expecting an object as a paramenter:

public ActionResult SendEmail(Contacts contacts)

Here is the view:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns" >
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendEmail", "Contacts", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "sendMessageArea" }, new { Name = "sendEmail" }))
    {
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend>Leave a message</legend>
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="row">                    
                    <div class="large-offset-2 large-8 columns">                        
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="large-2 columns">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-8 columns">                                    
                                    @Html.TextBox("Name", Model.Name, new { placeholder = "Your name..." })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-2 columns">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="large-2 columns">
                                    <div class="form-group">                                        
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EMail, new { @class = "control-label" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-8 columns">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.TextBox("EMail", Model.EMail, new { placeholder = "Your email..." })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EMail)
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-2 columns">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="large-2 columns">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "control-label" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-8 columns">                                    
                                        @Html.TextArea("Message", Model.Message, new { placeholder = "Your message here...", @class = "comment-control", id = "message" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)                                    
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-2 columns">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="large-offset-8 large-3 columns">
                                    <input type='submit' style='position:absolute;top:0;left:-9999px;width:1px;height:1px' />
                                    <a class='submit-button' href="javascript:sendEmail.submit()">
                                        <span class='submit-button-inner'>Submit</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-2 columns">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }
</div>
```

and the partial view:

```
<span class="success label">@Resources.Contacts.Index.SuccessSendMessage</span>
```

I think the problem should be related with the routeValues parameter because if I use a simple example without the htmlAttributes and routeValues it works well.
Any guess?

Comment: Can you post your complete View code?

Comment: I update the post with the view code